# Is there anyway to prevent access to Elasticsearch built-in API's such as /_nodes? , /_cluster, /_cat etc.?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, networking, acl, topology

I'm new to Elasticsearch and have very basic understanding of elasticsearch.

> So, let me first give little description about my problem statement. In my organisation, we have elasticsearch cluster made up of 3-nodes on unix boxes.  `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xx.xx.xx.1", "xx.xx.xx.2", "xx.xx.xx.3"]` . Everything works fine, but within the organisation private network one can access the Elasticsearch built-in API's such as `/_nodes? , /_cluster, etc` using the private IP's.

How do I prevent such unauthorised access to the API's internal to the network?? Is there any ACL feature in elasticsearch or do I have to install some nginx web server on top of it and block access to the url's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [x-pack basic security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html) which is included for free in the latest versions of Elasticsearch and **provide username/password based access** and many more ways to control the access, refer [x-pack license detail](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) for more info